# “Sound of a heavy rain” vs. “Sound of heavy raining”

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles, gerunds, nouns, indefinite-article

I came across this sentence.

> - it is sound of a heavy rain.

So why isn’t this way:

> it is sound of heavy raining.

I used raining instead of rain because, I think, rain fits more into the context, and raining depicts the process of rain coming down.

- when do we use articles before rain?

> - it is sound of a heavy rain

Comment: "It is sound of a heavy rain" is ungrammatical as a standalone sentence, because we need an article before **sound**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this sentence:

> It is the sound of **a** heavy rain.

the idea is that this *particular* sound can be identified as the sound of an instance of rain which is heavy *relative to other rainfalls*. The indefinite article specifies "instance" or "generic/paradigmatic instance".

So the sentence is not about the *ongoingness* of the rain, but the *sort* of rain the rain is.

Compare:

> It was the yippy bark of a small dog.

versus

> The yippy barking made it hard to concentrate on her algebra homework.

In the first sentence, the *type* of bark is being identified: it belongs to a small breed of dog.  In the second sentence, the ongoing/repetitive aspect of the bark is being emphasized.

Comment: Is writing "heavy raining" correct?

Comment: *heavy raining* is not what native speakers would call a downpour. They would call it *a heavy rain* or they would say *it is raining heavily*.

Answer (score 5):

**of** is a preposition, and prepositions must be followed by a noun. With many verbs, you can make a noun-form (called a gerund) by adding -ing to the verb. Generally we only do this when there isn't already a suitable noun. English people like to talk about rain, so there are many suitable nouns, and at least two are suitable: **rain** and **rainfall**. It therefore isn't necessary (and sounds wrong) to use the gerund **of heavy raining**.

We use **a** before a singular, countable noun to indicate that we are referring to a non-specific whatever-it-is.

For non-countable nouns like **rain** (note the U after **noun** in [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rain)), we don't normally put **a** in front of it:

> it is the sound of heavy rain

The exception is if we wish to refer to a non-specific example of a particular type of something. Here is another example where a non-count noun is qualified by an adjective:

> The colour of old claret
>   The colour of an old claret

The first sentence suggests that there are many types of claret, that old claret is one of these types, and that it has a particular colour. The second sentence further suggests that there are many types of old claret, but any non-specific one of them has (within reasonable limits) this particular colour.

In your sentence, **a heavy rain** suggests that there are many types of heavy rain, but they all have (within reasonable limits) the same sound. While this meaning is possible, it is, in my opinion, unlikely.

**storm** is countable (note the C in [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/storm)), so for a non-specific storm you would always include an indefinite article **a**:

> it is the sound of a heavy storm